# StreamReader data input to dictionary

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to have the values from my output(from streamreader and reading it line by line) to a dictionary using c#. The output looks like below mentioned screenshot where it executes on each file basis. The shown output is just for 1 file and there are multiple files output similar to that.

I wanted to assign the filepath [E.g. c:\testing\sp1aexpress_ru.exe] as key and the rest of the values to the values into the dictionary. Can you please suggest on how I can achieve this task?

So far I have written the below code. Inspite of Console.WriteLine(line) I want to input this to dictionary.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = Pathdir + "\\test.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a -h -s " + dir;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();

using (StreamReader streamReader = process.StandardOutput)
{
    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Output:

**c:\testing\sp1aexpress_ru.exe:**

Verified: Signed

Signing date:11:29 AM 1/27/2003

Signing date:11:29 AM 1/27/2003

Cert Status: Signed

Valid Usage: Code Signing

Cert Issuer: Microsoft Code Signing PCA

Serial Number:  61 07 11 43 00 00 00 00 00 34

Thumbprint:  282D9806C3DF7345929F64F5895EF2EA4AC29302

**c:\testing\WindowsRightsManagementServicesSP2-KB979099-Client-amd64-ENU.exe:**

Verified: Signed

Signing date:1:35 PM 1/14/2010

Signing date:1:35 PM 1/14/2010

Signers:

Microsoft Corporation

Cert Status: Signed

Valid Usage: Code Signing

Cert Issuer: Microsoft Code Signing PCA

Serial Number:  61 01 CF 3E 00 00 00 00 00 0F

Thumbprint:  9617094A1CFB59AE7C1F7DFDB6739E4E7C40508F

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Read it line by line, split on the first colon and assign to key-value pairs? What have you tried?

Comment: @Rango Thanks, just updated

Comment: Post text instead of a picture.  I can write the code easily if I have the text.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, I just re-updated my output sample

Comment: Having to parse this text is very little joy.  Just don't use the Process class, google "c# read certificate from file" to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky and probably won't work first time.  I've been parsing text files for over 40 years and always have to make some minor tweaks with complicated formats especially when you have multiple signers like this code.   Try code and let me know if there are any issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication91
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Certificate.Add(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public enum STATE
    {
        HEADER_FIRST_ROW,
        HEADER_NOT_FIRST_ROW,
        SIGNER_NAME,
        SIGNER_DATA
    }
    public class Certificate
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Certificate> certificateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Certificate>();

        public string filename { get;set;}
        public string verified { get; set; }
        public DateTime signingDate1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime signingDate2 { get; set; }
        public string catalog { get; set; }
        public List<Signer> signers { get; set; }

        public static void Add(string filename)
        {
            IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";
            Certificate certificate = null;
            int dateCount = 0;
            Signer signer = null;
            string name = "";
            string value = "";
            STATE state = STATE.HEADER_FIRST_ROW;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case STATE.HEADER_FIRST_ROW:
                            certificate = new Certificate();
                            certificate.filename = line;
                            certificateDictionary.Add(certificate.filename, certificate);
                            dateCount = 0;
                            state = STATE.HEADER_NOT_FIRST_ROW;
                            break;
                        case STATE.HEADER_NOT_FIRST_ROW:
                            name = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(":")).Trim();
                            value = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();

                            switch (name)
                            {
                                case "Verified":
                                    certificate.verified = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Signing date":
                                    if (dateCount == 0)
                                    {
                                        dateCount = 1;
                                        certificate.signingDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "h:mm tt M/dd/yyyy", provider);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        certificate.signingDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "h:mm tt M/dd/yyyy", provider);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Catalog":
                                    certificate.catalog = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Signers":
                                    state = STATE.SIGNER_NAME;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE.SIGNER_NAME:
                            if(certificate.signers == null) certificate.signers = new List<Signer>();
                            signer = new Signer();
                            certificate.signers.Add(signer);
                            signer.name = line;
                            state = STATE.SIGNER_DATA;
                            break;
                        case STATE.SIGNER_DATA:
                            name = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(":")).Trim();
                            value = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim();

                            switch (name)
                            {
                                case "Cert Status":
                                    signer.certificateStatus = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Valid Usage":
                                    signer.validUsage = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Cert Issuer":
                                    signer.certIssuer = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Serial Number":
                                    signer.serialNumber = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Thumbprint":
                                    signer.thumbPrint  = value;
                                    break;
                                case "Valid from":
                                    signer.fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "h:mm tt M/dd/yyyy", provider);
                                    break;
                                case "Valid to":
                                    signer.toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "h:mm tt M/dd/yyyy", provider);
                                    state = STATE.SIGNER_NAME;
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        public class Signer
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string certificateStatus { get; set; }
            public string validUsage { get; set; }
            public string certIssuer { get; set; }
            public string serialNumber { get; set; }
            public string thumbPrint { get; set; }
            public DateTime fromDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime toDate { get; set; }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What if this code runs on a system with a different locale? Or what if a different Windows version returns slightly different headings?